# Use two persistent stores and sync all changes to both?

Tags: ios, core-data

I would like to use two persistent stores; one SQLite store to store locally, and another AFIncrementalStore to sync changes remotely. I want both stores to have exactly the same information by sending changes from local to remote when the local context saves and by polling for changes on remote.

I'd like to have something like setting both stores in the same persistent store coordinator but that seems to be used only for splitting objects' locations between different stores.

How can I keep two persistent stores in (eventual) sync?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this construction?

Comment: @Wain the same data in a local sqlite database and on a server without needing to write out long methods to copy changed objects between the two.

Answer (score 0):

This seems trivial. You can create a central method that saves to both stores and access it via a singleton. You then call this method rather than the usual frame work `save`.

Comment: If the stores are not in the same PSC the objects cannot be saved to both. If they are in the same PSC the context chooses a single store per object.

Comment: You need two contexts and two PSCs. You will have to copy everything in your save method if you want different store formats.